# list file key-pair sorted by time

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, ls

I need to sort a filename pair sorted by time. Every file starts with AUSZUG or UMSATZ (and some numbers after). But the problem is that I cannot sort it by just time because some files can be uploaded (created) not as pair. For example, default sort:

```
ls -ltr --time-style "long-iso" {UMSATZ,AUSZUG}* | head -n 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 14:59 UMSATZ_2107381391.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 14:59 AUSZUG_2107381391.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:00 UMSATZ_1111111122.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:00 AUSZUG_1111111122.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:00 UMSATZ_9785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:00 AUSZUG_9785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:17 UMSATZ_6785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:17 AUSZUG_6785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:45 AUSZUG_8785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:45 AUSZUG_5785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:45 UMSATZ_8785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:45 UMSATZ_5785745789.TXT.GPG
```

You can see, UMSATZ pair for `AUSZUG_5785745789.TXT.GPG` are in last line

I can solve this by sort

```
ls -ltr --time-style "long-iso" {UMSATZ,AUSZUG}* | sort -t "_" -k 2 | head -n 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:00 AUSZUG_1111111122.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:00 UMSATZ_1111111122.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 14:59 AUSZUG_2107381391.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 14:59 UMSATZ_2107381391.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:45 AUSZUG_5785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:45 UMSATZ_5785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:17 AUSZUG_6785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:17 UMSATZ_6785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:45 AUSZUG_8785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:45 UMSATZ_8785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:00 AUSZUG_9785745789.TXT.GPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2015-05-04 15:00 UMSATZ_9785745789.TXT.GPG
```

But now it's not by the time :( Anyone idea to sort it by AUSZUG-UMSATZ pair sorted by time?

Comment: If *auszug_a* has a date after *auszug_b* but before *umsatz_b*, how should they be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got you right, I understand that you want to have a list of `UMSATZ_*` files sorted by time interlaced with the corresponding `AUSZUG_*` files. You can get this in bash with this one-liner:

```
ls -t UMSATZ_* | while read x; do echo "$x"; echo "AUSZUG${x#UMSATZ}"; done
```

The unusually looking `${x#UMSATZ}` strips the string `UMSATZ` from the front of the `x` variable.

Comment: Solved :) Thanks for idea, good idea. even better that is on one line :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply just find all of the `UMSATZ*` files by time, and then list the `AUSZUG*` one for each of the `UMSATZ*` you find:

```
ls -tr UMSATZ* | while read file
do
    sans_prefix=${file#UMZATZ}
    ls -ld *$sans_prefix
done
```

Or something like this... The `${file#UMSATZ}` removes the prefix `UMSATZ` from `$file`, so that if `$file` equals `UMSATZ_1111111122.TXT.GPG`, then `$sans_prefix` equals `_1111111122.TXT.GPG`. The `*$sans_prefix` should list both files with the same numeric suffix.